# Linker error trying to call extern "C" function from dll

Tags: c++, dll, linker, c++-cli

I'm trying to use a C++ class from a native .dll project in a C++/CLI .dll project. Visual Studio 2010, .NET Framework 3.5. So far this is what I have:

```
// This is a common macro:
#ifdef ISDLL
#define DLL __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLL __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

NativeProject:
   //INativeType.h: 
   class DLL INativeType {
       public:
           virtual void Foo() = 0;
   };

    //NativeType.h: 
    class DLL NativeType : public INativeType {
        public:
            virtual void Foo(); 
    };

    extern "C" DLL INativeType CreateNativeType();

    //NativeType.cpp: 
    void NativeType::Foo() {} 
    extern "C" DLL INativeType* CreateNativeType() { 
        return new NativeType(); 
    }

C++/CLI Project:
    // Wrapper.h:
    #include "INativeType.h"
    ref class Wrapper {
        INativeType* m_nativeType;
    };

    // Wrapper.cpp:
    #include "Wrapper.h"
    #include "NativeType.h"
    // in some method:
        m_nativeType = CreateNativeType();
```

This gives me the following linker error:

```
error LNK2028: unresolved token (...) "extern "C" class INativeType * __stdcall CreateNativeType(void)"" ... in Wrapper.obj
```

Also, although the functions are correctly exported in NativeProject.dll, as I verified it with DependencyWalker, the linker also gives this warning:

```
warning LNK4199: /DELAYLOAD:NativeProject.dll ignored; no imports found from NativeProject.dll
```

The C++/CLI project is configured to delay load NativeProject.dll and also includes NativeProject.lib in its linker options. At this point I don't know how to diagnose this linker error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it's not `extern "C"` because your code is C++.  They are not the same thing.

Comment: @TonyTheLion Are you saying they shouldn't be declared "extern "C""?

Comment: I don't see any C, so why declare it as `extern "C"`, when there is none?

Comment: It's just how all the tutorials I've seen do it. It doesn't fix the error to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just let the C++/CLI project instantiate the class directly instead of with a factory method?

Besides that, it just looks like you are re-inventing COM (using objects through interfaces). I would just instantiate full-blown C++ classes or, if you really need it, use full-blown COM.

**EDIT:** Make sure the factory method's calling convention is the same in both the client and the DLL.

Comment: You can't directly call the constructor of a class that's dynamically loaded; using a factory method declared outside the class seems like the generally accepted way of doing that. See for instance http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/9b39ab21-91ac-488c-9001-13de51566497

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I had changed the calling convention to __stdcall. Changing it back to __cdecl fixed these errors. Problem solved, apparently.

Comment: If you update your answer to include the solution you helped me find, I'll accept and upvote it. :)